# Preventing transposition of Series from idxmax

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Basic question here. This is my DataFrame:

```
     year  month        lat        lon          mld
0    1950      1  63.650173 -26.497180   775.628000
1    1950      2  60.427250 -36.825043  1849.504200
2    1950      3  60.427250 -36.825043  2387.679200
3    1950      4  60.427250 -36.825043  1129.635600
4    1950      5  63.650173 -26.497180   732.966740
..    ...    ...        ...        ...          ...
775  2014      8  63.650173 -26.497180    20.319588
776  2014      9  64.766655 -30.303265    32.141790
777  2014     10  63.650173 -26.497180    67.101660
778  2014     11  64.157326 -31.469580    72.267710
779  2014     12  65.369200 -29.106660   185.468500
```

I am trying to build a new dataframe using the row with the maximum value of mld for each year.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv('mld\\mlotst_Omon_UKESM1-0-LL_historical_mldls_1950-2014.csv')
list_df = []
for yyyy in range(1950, 2015):
    yyyy_df = df[df['year'] == yyyy]
    print(yyyy_df)
    idx_max = yyyy_df['mld'].idxmax()
    list_df.append(df.iloc[idx_max])
#big_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns )
big_df = pd.concat(list_df)
```

However, the Series I get from `df.iloc[idx_max])` is transposed so my final dataframe is not at all what I wanted.

```
big_df
Out[36]: 
year     1950.000000
month       3.000000
lat        60.427250
lon       -36.825043
mld      2387.679200
    
year     2014.000000
month       3.000000
lat        63.650173
lon       -26.497180
mld       884.261800
Length: 325, dtype: float64
```

Would someone please show me the idiomatic way of doing this? I want my output dataframe to be in the same format as my input dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) and [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to get what you want:

```py
idx = df.groupby(['year'])['mld'].idxmax()  
max_mld_df = df.loc[idx]
```

Comment: Thanks so much! [My mind is stuck in nump(t)y land.]

Answer (score 0):

use sort_values and groupby + tail (becuz ascending=True)

```
df.sort_values('mld').groupby('year').tail(1)
```

or sort_values and drop_duplicates

```
df.sort_values('mld', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('year')
```